# The update with the "xxx" ID doesn't exist. Verify the ID and try again

Tags: magento2

In my enterprise, I have a situation where my staging content is messed up for a product.

I can see the active staging content by going into `Content > Content staging > Dashboard` but it doesn't reflect in the product itself.

Obviously, because of this, staged content is not applied and not able to delete it either.

When saving the product it throws this error:

> The update with the "xxx" ID doesn't exist. Verify the ID and try
> again.

**How do I clean up this?** I don't want to delete the product. If I could delete the staged content (scheduled content).

Comment: any luck? I am facing the same issue M2 EE [2.3.3]

Answer (score 2):

I've just fixed this issue on a magento 2.3.5-p2 commerce cloud store. The error message is referencing a missing update row in the staging_updates table.

In the catalog_product_entity table for the product there will be a reference in the updated_in or created_in columns to this missing update id.

The fix I did was to create a dummy rollback entry in the staging_updates table with this SQL query

```
INSERT INTO `staging_update` (`start_time`, `name`, `description`, `rollback_id`, `is_campaign`, `is_rollback`, `moved_to`)
VALUES
  ('2022-06-17 13:20:00', 'Temp Rollback', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL);
```

Then I edited the auto incremented id to match the missing one, and then my product changes could be saved.

This caused a loss of pending changes for my product, but it allowed it to be edited and saved again successfully.

Comment: Hello I am facing the same issue and looks like something is deleting these rows. For me its happing for multiple products So I am still looking for some better solution.

Comment: a magento cron runs which delete unused id rows. but some times it is deleting the used rows also.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone know, why we are getting this issue. I am also getting this issue when I try to save some of the categories. The above mentioned solution fixed the issue, but need to know the root cause and prevent is from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `created_in` value of the entity table `1` in case you need to avoid saving errors. otherwise, make an entry with the id in the `staging_update` table.